# how to filter two multidimensional array's?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all, I have seen the "similar" questions, none of them solve my problem, what I need is that the "impuesto" value of the array "a" is equal to the key of the array "b". and if not, remove those that are not equal to the array "b"

I have two multidimensional arrays (a and b). and I need to filter all those who are not in the first

Example:

a)

```
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(11) "recaudacion"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(36) "Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(28) "Regimen General de Retencion"
      }
```

b)

```
  ["recaudacion"]=>
  array(1) {
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-07"
  }
  ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
  array(1) {
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-13"
  }
  ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
  array(1) {
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-16"
  }
```

result:

```
    ["recaudacion"]=>
  array(1) {
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-07"
  }
  ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
  array(1) {
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-13"
  }
```

Here you can see the original arrays

a)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [257]=>
    array(18) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(38) "Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(11) "recaudacion"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(64) "Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(36) "Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(28) "Regimen General de Retencion"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(41) "Regimen General de Percepcion (Devengado)"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(46) "Comercializacion de Combustibles liquidos deri"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(44) "Registro Seccional de la Propiedad Automotor"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(19) "Entidades Bancarias"
      }
      [9]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(60) "Companias de Seguros Embarcaciones Deportivas y Recreaciones"
      }
      [10]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(21) "Empresas de Servicios"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(20) "Regimen simplificado"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(3) "IVA"
      }
      [13]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(29) "EMPLEADOR-APORTES SEG. SOCIAL"
      }
      [14]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(25) "REGIMENES DE INFORMACIÓN"
      }
      [15]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(52) "Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"
      }
      [16]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(29) "PRESENTAC. DJ RET. Y/O PERCEP"
      }
      [17]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(28) "SICORE-IMPTO.A LAS GANANCIAS"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [258]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(19) "Impuestos de Sellos"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(69) "Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(51) "Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

b)

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [257]=>
    array(8) {
      ["recaudacion"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-07"
      }
      ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-13"
      }
      ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-16"
      }
      ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-10"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [258]=>
    array(8) {
      ["recaudacion"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-07"
      }
      ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-13"
      }
      ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-17"
      }
      ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-00"
      }
      ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
      array(1) {
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2017-10-10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you need to see the code just ask for it, there will be no problem in showing it

Comment: *Please, do not abuse the blockquote,* I have edited your post but still remember it in the future.

Comment: thanks mega, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve this by using nested foreach loop, you can try my code here: [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca65f9d28f09efaea98c13586de1e02d27ccc5ad), it keeps the same a array except keys from b array.

Comment: It works excellent, however I also need the date eg: '2017-10-00'

Comment: You can get the date value from the $b array and put it beside "impuesto" array, I updated the php sandox for you to see how

Comment: [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cf9233c7d9dc594456286afb2120740a1de6a27)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use array_key_exists.  So you loop on the values from array a) and check if they exists in array b). If they do, put them in the result array.  Like this:

```
$arraya = array(
                1 => array("impuesto" => "recaudacion"),
                3 => array("impuesto" => "Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"),
                4 => array("impuesto" => "Regimen General de Retencion")
               );

$arrayb = array(
                "recaudacion" => array(9 => "2017-10-07"),
                "Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral" => array(9 => "2017-10-13"),
                "Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion" => array(9 => "2017-10-16")
               );

echo "<pre>\n";
echo "ARRAY A\n";
print_r($arraya);
echo "\nARRAY B\n";
print_r($arrayb);

# filter
$result = array();
foreach ($arraya as $key => $value)
{
    $impuesto_value = "$value[impuesto]";
    if (array_key_exists($impuesto_value, $arrayb))
    {
        $result[$impuesto_value] = $arrayb[$impuesto_value];
    }
}

echo "\nRESULT ARRAY\n";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

This will output the following:

> ```
> ARRAY A
> Array
> (
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [impuesto] => recaudacion
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [impuesto] => Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral
>         )
>
>     [4] => Array
>         (
>             [impuesto] => Regimen General de Retencion
>         )
>
> )
>
> ARRAY B
> Array
> (
>     [recaudacion] => Array
>         (
>             [9] => 2017-10-07
>         )
>
>     [Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral] => Array
>         (
>             [9] => 2017-10-13
>         )
>
>     [Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion] => Array
>         (
>             [9] => 2017-10-16
>         )
>
> )
>
> RESULT ARRAY
> Array
> (
>     [recaudacion] => Array
>         (
>             [9] => 2017-10-07
>         )
>
>     [Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral] => Array
>         (
>             [9] => 2017-10-13
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: thank you, you have approached me much to my goal, I tried it on a tester as you gave it to me and it works, however I can not implement it in my code ... it returns an empty array

Comment: At this point, it is easier to start another question with the new code, as debugging code form the comments is very difficult.